# Oracle 10g: column is blank, but is not null or an empty string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table that is blank. The weird thing is that it does not appear to be null or an empty string. So, if I do this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE column IS NULL
```

...or:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE column = ''
```

I get nothing. Thoughts?

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` statement -- if the column is CHAR, then space characters will be allocated for the number designated in the CHAR declaration.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TRIM(column) = ''` return anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Issue this query:

```
SELECT column, DUMP(column, 1016)
FROM table
```

It'll show the exact contents.

*Related: Oracle does not allow empty strings; they're silently converted to `NULL`.*

Answer (score 16):

Maybe the column contains only spaces?

Did you try

```
select * 
from table 
where trim(column) is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's got a basically permanent annoyance that empty strings are treated as null. However, are you sure that's an empty string? It could be an otherwise invisible character, such as a space or tab/linebreak/linefeed/etc... What does the string length show when you do `select length(column) from table`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM TABLE   
 WHERE TRIM(column) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column is not `VARCHAR2` but `CHAR(N)` then insertion of an empty string is padded. See [what Tom Kyte tells about this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5984520277372)

Comment: Here is the what happened... Looks like there was a 0 byte character in the column. By using rawtohex function I found this out. This is what I had to do to trim: trim(chr(0) from column)